# Storing a pair key-value in a B-Tree

Tags: c++, treenode, b-tree, abstract-data-type

I'm working in a B-Tree, but I can't undesrstand how it works.

Looking for some examples, I've found this [page](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/b-tree-set-1-introduction-2/) that explains how to write the code for this structure.

The problem is:

```
class BTreeNode {
    private
        int *keys;  // An array of keys
        int t;      // Minimum degree (defines the range for number of keys)
        BTreeNode **C; // An array of child pointers
        int n;     // Current number of keys
        bool leaf; // Is true when node is leaf. Otherwise false
    public:
        BTreeNode(int _t, bool _leaf);   // Constructor

    friend class BTree;
};
```

If it is the node of my tree, that stores all the keys in some range, in which part can I found my data?
Suppose that I want to store a string, how can I get that string?

I want to get something like:

```
BTree.insert(1,'hello');
BTree.insert(2,' ');
BTree.insert(3,'world');
BTree.insert(4,'!');
```

Then, when I want to get some data by its associated ID...

```
BTree.getById(4);
```

But, how can I declare my node strcture for something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: What is a B-tree? Maybe you can expand the B? Binary tree? If binary, each node cannot have more than 2 children.

Comment: @armanali A B-tree is a tree with zero or more children per node. A binary tree is said-same, with a top-end restriction of no more than two children per node. B-trees usually use a page of keys per node, with children indicating sub keys that are "less" than the first key (the left-mode child), "between" each pair of keys (the inner children), and "greater" than the last key (the right-most child). Thus a node with a page of N keys can/will N+1 children. A binary tree is a B-tree with a *single* key (page of one) per node, there by having possible children that are "lesser" or "greater".

Comment: Incorrect http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez you can explain at your leisure how anything I stated in that comment is *not* true. Both the description and the graphics on wiki, if anything, *confirm* everything I stated. The details of specific *orders* of b-trees are left to the implementer, but the general algorithms and design remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, two things.

Firstly, remember to use double quotes `"` when referring to strings. Single quotes refer to a single character and you will get errors.

Secondly, the code you have linked is made to store integers. Yes, you can expand it to store your own type but I recommend trying to understand what it is doing with the integers first.

Once you understand that, expand the class to a template, or simply declare the keytype (currently int) to be a key-value pair instead.